# AutoMapper Child Entities with pre created Mapping

Tags: c#, automapper

I have this mapping created:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserModel>()
   .ForMember(um => um.UID, mo => mo.MapFrom(s => s.Id));
```

I am about to create this mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Blog, BlogModel>()
   .ForMember(bm => bm.Author, mc => mc.MapFrom(m => m.Author));
```

So `Author` is a `User` in the `Blog` but in the `BlogModel` I want the reduced amount of information.

My question is that when the `Blog` gets mapped, will it use the `User` mapping, or how do I get it to use that mapping configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source Object

[image]

Target Object

[image]

Object Mapping

[image]

Comment: thnx for the comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will. Here is sample:

[image: Mapped]

Now, remove your mapping, you'll see an exception because AutoMapper is not aware of how to convert your entities:

[image]

Also, if you want to map part of your models or different types of mappings, take a look at [Value Resolver class](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers). You can use it then as the following:

```
public class YourCustomResolver : ValueResolver<FromModel, ToPartOfModel>
{
    protected override ToPartOfModel ResolveCore(FromModel)
    {
        // Your manual mapping or another call to AutoMapper
    }
}

// Configuring mapper
AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<FromModel, ToModel>().
    ForMember(o => o.ImageLogoMin, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<YourCustomResolver >().ConstructedBy(() => new YourCustomResolver ()));
```

Hope it helps.